# Why should I write required init() {}?

Tags: swift, init

I don't understand why I get the compiler error:

> Constructing an object of class type 'Self' with a metatype value must use a 'required' initializer`

[image]

Below is full code.

```
class ParentFactory {
    static func create() -> Self {
        return self.init()
    }
    
//    required init(){}
    
    func printMessage() {
        print("Super")
    }
}

class Child1Factory: ParentFactory {
    override func printMessage() {
        print("1 Class")
    }
}

class Child2Factory: ParentFactory {
    override func printMessage() {
        print("2 Class")
    }
}


class Factory {
    static func createFactory(_ type: String) -> ParentFactory {
        if type == "1" {
            return Child1Factory.create()
        } else {
            return Child2Factory.create()
        }
    }
}
```

If I write `required init() {}`, the error does not occur. I don't understand why I need `required init` even if it doesn't have any code in the initializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Swift documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/initialization/#Default-Initializers)

> Swift provides a *default initializer* for any structure or class that provides default values for all of its properties and doesn’t provide at least one initializer itself. The default initializer simply creates a new instance with all of its properties set to their default values.

Your `ParentFactory` has no stored properties and so, in theory, the default initialiser will be created and should be sufficient.  But, you have used the meta type `Self`, so you aren't necessarily instantiating a `ParentFactory` - It could be a subclass of `ParentFactory`, and indeed this is what you are doing.

Now, imagine if `Child1Factory` looked like this:

```
class Child1Factory: ParentFactory {
    let aProperty: Int
    
    init(number: Int) {
        self.aProperty = number
        super.init()
    }

    override func printMessage() {
        print("1 Class")
    }
}
```

This is a perfectly valid implementation - We have an initialiser that initialises the class properties and that calls the superclass initialiser. However, I can't say `let child = Child1Factory()` - That initialiser doesn't exist, but this is exactly what you are doing when you call `Child1Factory.create` and it executes `Self.init()`.

To protect against this, your parent class must have a required init that matches the signature of the `Self` init - That way it is guaranteed that this class and all subclasses will have an `init` with that signature.

It doesn't matter that the initialiser is empty.  What matters is that you are ensuring that all subclasses can be called with that initialiser signature.